# How to use raw_input() in QGIS python console?

Tags: qgis, python

I'm hoping to use raw_input() inside a loop to prompt the user when s/he wants to continue running the script. However, I'm getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Is this function supported in qgis' python console? If not, do you have any suggestion?

I don't need to read the user's input. I just need the loop to pause for a while to let the user do some other stuff, then when ready, to resume working again.

Comment: I'm not sure waiting for the user like this is a good idea.  Why not make a UI for your script and turning it into a plugin.

Comment: You're probably right Nathan. It's supposed to be a quick and dirty script, and I haven't learned how to write a plugin yet. :) oh, btw, it needs to pause because the script is also doing some counting.

Comment: The [QGIS Plugin Builder](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/plugin-builder) plugin can give you a jump start with making your first plugin.

Answer (score 3):

The alternative to raw_input is QInputDialog.getText as explained in Maximus' answer above.  A quick and Dirty example would be:

```
##Import libraries
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.utils import *

from PyQt4.QtGui import QInputDialog #this is for your dialogs

 tempTuple = QInputDialog.getText(None, "Your Name" ,"Enter your Full Name: ")
 userName = tempTuple[0]
```

see also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707849/link-qinputdialog-text-to-a-variable

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution that works for me in QGIS 3.10

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in PyQGIS. This is what i found
http://mappinggis.com/2015/09/feed-back-como-introducir-valores-a-traves-de-pyqgis/

Comment: Please edit your answer to give a little more information - external links are notorious for going bad.

Comment: Also, this is a link to a page in Spanish, FYI

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but the problem seems to persist as of QGis v2.18.

I was able to work around this issue by installing the IPython QGIS Console plugin and running my script from there.

Answer (score 0):

This [bug report](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/9894) indicates that neither input() nor raw_input() are currently supported, nor likely to be any time soon. Bummer...